# Bootstrap datepicker not working with format and startdate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to set start date to 21 yrs back date and show the date in d/m/y format.The date is coming in d/m/y format but start date is not working

```
$('#date_of_birth').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   startDate: '2015-04-15',
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

the input field is :

```
<input id="date_of_birth" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-provide="datepicker">
```

Please help.

Comment: What version of jquery and bootstrap are you on?

Comment: And are you seeing any console errors

Comment: jquery-1.11.0.min and bootstrap 3.3.1

Comment: no console error for help

Comment: You're meeting the requirements for that module at least

Answer (score 2):

startDate is for the earliest date you can select. As @seth-mcclaine suggested, adding '-21y' works:

```
$('#date_of_birth').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   startDate: '-21y',
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Do you mean to use defaultViewDate instead? Ex:

```
$("#date").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true,
        defaultViewDate: {
            month: '04',            
            day:'15',
            year: '2000'
        },
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' 
});
```

I used jQuery 1.11.0 and Bootstrap 3.3.1 to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation here:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

And the following example:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
})
```

I would expect you to be able to do the following:

```
$('#date_of_birth').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   startDate: '-21y', //or '-21Y'
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Comment: i went through the whole doc.I have tried every possible sol but nothing is working.Is it a version issue?how do i know that?